# Can't send a message to a specific channel

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, discord.js, quick.db

I'm trying to create a modmail system and whenever I try to make it, it says "channel.send is not a function, here is my code."

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js")
const client = new Discord.Client()
const db = require('quick.db')
// ...
client.on('message', message => {
  if(db.fetch(`ticket-${message.author.id}`)){
    if(message.channel.type == "dm"){
      const channel = client.channels.cache.get(id => id.name == `ticket-${message.author.id}`)
      channel.send(message.content)
    }
  }
})
// ...
client.login("MYTOKEN")
```

I'm trying this with version 12.0.0

**EDIT:**
I found my issue, for some reason the saved ID is the bots ID, not my ID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As MrMythical said, you should use the `find` function instead of `get`. I believe the issue is that you're grabbing a non-text channel, since `channel` is defined, you just can't send anything to it.

You could fix this by adding an additional catch to ensure you are getting a text channel, and not a category or voice channel. I would also `return` (or do an error message of sorts) if `channel` is undefined.

**Discord.js v12:**

```js
const channel = client.channels.cache.find(c => c.name === `ticket-${message.author.id}` && c.type === 'text');
```

**Discord.js v13:**

```js
const channel = client.channels.cache.find(c => c.name === `ticket-${message.author.id}` && c.type === 'GUILD_TEXT');
```

**Edit:**
You can tell `channel` is defined because if it weren't it would say something along the lines of: `Cannot read property 'send' of undefined`.

Comment: Its only defined in the creation of the ticket (Inside another client.on() function)

Comment: I just got the error `Cannot read property 'send' of undefined` when I tried your fix

Comment: And you're 100% sure the channel you are trying to find exists and your bot has access to it?

Comment: After taking another look at your code I decided to mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to find it with a function. Use `.find` for that instead:

```js
const channel = client.channels.cache.find(id => id.name == `ticket-${message.author.id}`)
```

Comment: I did that earlier and it didn't work

Comment: Does the channel exist for sure?